Why was Tolkien so "non-secretive" while creating The Lord of the Rings?
I am currently reading The Return of the Shadow ("HoME 6").
Shockingly (to me), Tolkien did the opposite of what I always had held true in my inner world: he did not have everything planned out before he started, but literally (at least in the beginning) just started writing it, chapter by chapter, with no real idea of where it was going.
He seemed to consider it merely a sequel to the The Hobbit, with "Bingo" essentially repeating Bilbo's desire for "an adventure" of an unspecified kind.
Not only this, which already both confuses and embarrasses me (since I have basically been preaching about how Tolkien's masterpiece was carefully thought-out in advance and not just written "as it happens"), but he even sent away (an early version of) the first chapter to some person (child) for them to "comment on", as if he was entirely unsure of his own skills.
As I understand it, The Hobbit was already quite a popular success at this time, and he was of course well underway with all the Middle-earth stories for The Silmarillion. It very much confuses me that he would want to send out such an early and short draft to an outsider in the first place, for any reason, but also that he dared risking ideas or even pages leaking long before he was finished with the book. He also wrote letters including details of these early ideas.
Wouldn't it have been better for him to keep it a secret and only release it once finished, instead of risking rumours of the plot to be discussed by the public prior to its release? That thought would stress me personally to such an extent that I would have been unable to complete it, but I guess I'm not Tolkien...

It was a different time, no internet. The parties liable to be discussing it in advance of publication would have been few and select.

instead of risking rumours of the plot to be discussed by the public prior to its release? What is so troubling about "rumours of the plot" being public? I mean, the moment a book is out, you can legally publish its plot with 100% traceability. And book covers usually explain part of the plot/setting. What sells a book is the storytelling, the plot "hero does something and defeats his enemy" is hardly a distinct selling point. Nowadays you can find the plot of each series or book as soon as they are public, yet people still consume series and books...

To put an analogy, the "plot" of the trolley problem is either you kill one people or you kill five. Yet what is interesting are the arguments in favor of either of the outcomes.

If you or I were to trying writing something like LotR, we would be quite wise to plot it out in advance. Tolkien was a rare genius.

So, why all these blockbuster movies have trailers?

In general, questions like this may be better off on writing.se.

he even sent away (an early version of) the first chapter to some person (child) for them to "comment on", this child was the son (Rayner) of the publisher Stanley Unwin, who read The Hobbit before it was published, on his father's request as a test of how good the book might be. Rayner's approval of The Hobbit helped it get published. Tolkien was keeping Stanley Unwin updated on his sequel's progress in letters and had a good working relationship, and Tolkien was interested to see how someone who gave a positive report on The Hobbit, but was at one step remove, would view his growing story.

There's nothing unusual about getting feedback on early drafts from trusted readers. The modern term for someone doing it is "beta reader" (as distinct from someone like a developmental editor who would actually be employed by a publisher). Getting someone else's opinion on your work is valuable for any author, regardless of their writing skills.
We know Tolkien was well aware of this because he was famously a member of the Inklings, an Oxford-based group of writers who met primarily to read and discuss each other's unfinished works. The first edition of The Lord of the Rings was dedicated to them.
A high-profile author today might be worried about spoilers leaking out but that wouldn't have been much of a concern for Tolkien, for a few reasons.
The Hobbit was certainly a successful children's book but not some massive, Harry Potter-like phenomenon with fans clamouring for any news of a sequel. In fact, modern notions of fandom didn't really exist at the time. Conventions and newsletters were starting to become a thing in the 1930s but it would be decades before they were significant or common enough to focus on single works rather than entire genres. The term "spoiler" itself didn't emerge until the 1970s and didn't really take hold until the internet made it easy for them to spread.
So if anyone untrustworthy did learn the plot of a Hobbit sequel, they had no way to tell the small number of people who might have cared about it.

You make a good point, but C. S. Lewis apparently felt that JRRT ignored the Inklings' comments. In one of his published letters he wrote, “No-one ever influenced Tolkien—you might as well try to influence a bandersnatch”.

Well, in the mentioned case it would be more of an alpha reader.
